# Issue Installing Bowtie2 and Samtools on Mac M2

Tags: installation, samtools, apple-m2, mambaforge, bowtie2

I am trying to install NGS analysis packages (bowtie2, samtools, etc) into mamba environments on my Mac M2, but am facing issues.

I am installing as follows:

```
    mamba activate myenv
    mamba install -c bioconda bowtie2
```

And I am getting the same error as described above:

```
    Could not solve for environment specs
    The following package could not be installed
    └─ bowtie2   does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).
```

I have the same issue with samtools. But many other packages are installing just fine.

I believe this is an issue with my M2, because when I do the exact same process on my lab's linux server (installing into mamba environment), it works without any issue.
Thank you!